# Voldemort Getting exception voldemort.store.InsufficientOperationalNodesException

Tags: berkeley-db, voldemort

We are getting following exption in production system some time examples out of 84mn call 10000 times we are getting this exception

voldemort.store.InsufficientOperationalNodesException: 1 get alls required, but 0 succeeded. Failing nodes : []

I tried to increase the Voldemort ClientConfig connection_timeout and sockettimeout but till getting this error.

Our config:

**stores.xml:**

```
<stores>
<store>
  <name>test</name>
  <persistence>bdb</persistence>
  <description>test</description>
  <owners>test</owners>
  <routing-strategy>consistent-routing</routing-strategy>
  <routing>client</routing>
  <replication-factor>1</replication-factor>
  <required-reads>1</required-reads>
  <required-writes>1</required-writes>
  <key-serializer>
    <type>string</type>
  </key-serializer>
  <value-serializer>
    <type>string</type>
  </value-serializer>
</store>
</stores>
```

**Server.properties**

```
node.id=0
# configs
admin.enable=true
admin.max.threads=40
bdb.cache.evictln=true
bdb.cache.size=12GB
bdb.checkpoint.interval.bytes=2147483648
bdb.checkpointer.off.batch.writes=true
bdb.cleaner.interval.bytes=15728640
bdb.cleaner.lazy.migration=false
bdb.cleaner.min.file.utilization=0
bdb.cleaner.threads=1
bdb.enable=true
bdb.evict.by.level=true
bdb.expose.space.utilization=true
bdb.lock.nLockTables=94
bdb.minimize.scan.impact=true
bdb.one.env.per.store=true
enable.server.routing=false
enable.verbose.logging=false
http.enable=true
nio.connector.selectors=100
num.scan.permits=2
request.format=vp3
restore.data.timeout.sec=1314000
scheduler.threads=24
slop.frequency.ms=300000
socket.enable=true
storage.configs=voldemort.store.bdb.BdbStorageConfiguration, 
voldemort.store.readonly.ReadOnlyStorageConfiguration
stream.read.byte.per.sec=209715200
stream.write.byte.per.sec=78643200
```

**cluster.xml**

```
<cluster>
        <name>myprodcluster</name>
        <server>
                <id>0</id>
                <host>192.168.1.10</host>
                <http-port>8081</http-port>
                <socket-port>6666</socket-port>
                <admin-port>7777</admin-port>
                <partitions>0, 1</partitions>
        </server>
</cluster>
```

We have single node cluster

Can you please help me how we can fix this issue

Comment: I am getting the same exception. It was working fine for couple of days. After that I started getting these exception a very few per day and getting increased day by day. Later on all the connections in that pool where turned invalid and all the requests are getting this exception. Please suggest how can I resolve this issue.

Thanks.